# Invalid template file error for overiding template using my custom theme

Tags: magento2

I m overriding result phtml template using my custom theme.

Here is what i have done

In my

```
   app\design\frontend\MyTheme\tagtheme\Magento_CatalogSearch\templates\
```

i have copied result.phtml from CatalogSearch view template folder.

I get log as :

[2016-08-18 12:54:13] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'result.phtml' in module: 'Vendor_Module' block's name: 'search.result' [] []

Should i have to override the layout file as well?

Comment: Let's start to discuss about your issue: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44159/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-sachin-s

Answer (score 0):

When overriding or re-using the Magento default templates in our custom module, we need to have a module prefix which corresponds with the templates. For example: `Vendor_Module::result.phtml` or `Magento_CatalogSearch::result.phtml`.

Comment: Where do we give that...Cause they say no need of xml when yu are overriding the phtml template using the theme method

Comment: You have a module `Vendor_Module`?

Comment: Yes...in Vendor_Module i had catalogsearch_result_index.xml which i removed after copying the phtml file from view layout to my theme

Comment: Now my Vendor_Module view frontend has nothing, but my templates are in the above path shown

Comment: Try to disable this module, flush Magento Cache,  delete `var/generation`,  `var/view_preprocessed`, may delete static content and try to rebuild again.

Comment: my theme phtml seems to be called when i put a die statement..Should i still proceed disabling the module?

Comment: Hey @Khoa , i disabled the module and clear all var gen and static content...i again get the same error :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44159/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-sachin-s).